# FileLoaderLoadException, Cannot import resource ... using FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.2

I use Symfony 2.2.1. and I'm trying to install FOSUserBundle. When I tried to create the database using `php app/console doctrine:schema:create --force`, the system display this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                 
Cannot import resource "D:\wamp\www\job\app/config\config.yml" from "D:\wamp\www\job\app/config/config_dev.yml"
```

Comment: You have an error in your config.yml as the error says. Fix it. Maybe missing `fos_user` configuration.

Comment: In most cases, this exception has a previous exception. Please try to request the page in a browser to view the previous exception, or use the -v option.

Comment: the problem is resolved. thank you :)

Comment: @taiebbaccouch Would you be so nice, and post your resolution as an answer to your question?

Comment: i just forgot to add this line : new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle() in the AppKernel.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue was that this line was missing in my AppKernel.php:

```
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
```